# PHP DOMDocument is not working well

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to fetch the email accounts from a web site using the following code. But it produces an out put like

```
%3e%61%2f%3c%6d%6f%63%2e%6c%69%61%6d%67%40%6f%63%73%6e%61%69%70%6d%61%20%3e%22%6d%6f%63%2e%6c%69%61%6d%67%40%6f%63%73%6e%61%69%70%6d%61%3a%6f%74%6c%69%61%6d%22%3d%66%65%72%68%20%61%3c %3e%61%2f%3c%6d%6f%63%2e%65%76%69%6c%40%34%34%34%73%71%20%3e%22%6d%6f%63%2e%65%76%69%6c%40%34%34%34%73%71%3a%6f%74%6c%69%61%6d%22%3d%66%65%72%68%20%61%3c %3e%61%2f%3c%6e%69%2e%70%6f%68%73%6c%61%74%69%67%69%64%6e%65%67%79%78%6f%40%6f%66%6e%69%20%3e%22%6e%69%2e%70%6f%68%73%6c%61%74%69%67%69%64%6e%65%67%79%78%6f%40%6f%66%6e%69%3a%6f%74%6c%69%61%6d%22%3d%66%65%72%68%20%61%3c %3e%61%2f%3c%6d%6f%63%2e%73%6e%61%72%6f%6f%6a%6e%61%6d%40%6f%66%6e%69%20%3e%22%6d%6f%63%2e%73%6e%61%72%6f%6f%6a%6e%61%6d%40%6f%66%6e%69%3a%6f%74%6c%69%61%6d%22%3d%66%65%72%68%20%61%3c %3e%61%2f%3c%6d%6f%63%2e%6c%69%61%6d%67%40%6c%65%74%6f%68%61%79%69%72%70%20%3e%22%6d%6f%63%2e%6c%69%61%6d%67%40%6c%65%74%6f%68%61%79%69%72%70%3a%6f%74%6c%69%61%6d%22%3d%66%65%72%68%20%61%3c %3e%61%2f%3c%6d%6f%63%2e%6c%69%61%6d%67%40%61%72%70%61%6e%6e%75%70%68%63%72%75%68%63%79%65%6e%6e%61%79%69%76%20%3e%22%6d%6f%63%2e%6c%69%61%6d%67%40%61%72%70%61%6e%6e%75%70%68%63%72%75%68%63%79%65%6e%6e%61%79%69%76%3a%6f%74%6c%69%61%6d%22%3d%66%65%72%68%20%61%3c %3e%61%2f%3c%6d%6f%63%2e%6c%69%61%6d%67%40%74%6e%65%6d%65%67%6e%61%6d%65%72%6f%63%6e%61%76%61%72%74%20%3e%22%6d%6f%63%2e%6c%69%61%6d%67%40%74%6e%65%6d%65%67%6e%61%6d%65%72%6f%63%6e%61%76%61%72%74%3a%6f%74%6c%69%61%6d%22%3d%66%65%72%68%20%61%3c %3e%61%2f%3c%6d%6f%63%2e%6b%75%65%67%6e%61%68%63%78%65%74%6e%65%6d%79%6f%6c%70%6d%65%65%68%74%40%68%73%65%72%75%73%20%3e%22%6d%6f%63%2e%6b%75%65%67%6e%61%68%63%78%65%74%6e%65%6d%79%6f%6c%70%6d%65%65%68%74%40%68%73%65%72%75%73%3a%6f%74%6c%69%61%6d%22%3d%66%65%72%68%20%61%3c %3e%61%2f%3c%6d%6f%63%2e%6c%69%61%6d%67%40%68%70%6e%6f%6d%62%61%6a%75%73%20%3e%22%6d%6f%63%2e%6c%69%61%6d%67%40%68%70%6e%6f%6d%62%61%6a%75%73%3a%6f%74%6c%69%61%6d%22%3d%66%65%72%68%20%61%3c
```

The code I am using is

```
<?php    
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://www.quickerala.com/listings?searchString=&districtId=1&go=Go');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//span[@class='listEmail']" );
foreach ($nodelist as $n){
    echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: in your internet explorer, right click the web page and then click view source. You will see it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that's actually correct. You have to manually [`urldecode`](http://sg.php.net/urldecode) it I think.

Correction, you also have to [`strrev`](http://sg.php.net/strrev) it.

It's probably a spam protection; from their code I manage to lift this nugget of code:

```
$(".listEmail").each(function(index){
    var strEm = unescape($(this).html());
    var reversedStr=strEm.split("").reverse().join("");
    $(this).html(reversedStr)});
}
```

So:

```
$value = strrev(urldecode($n->nodeValue));
```

That still returns a piece of HTML, so you have to parse that as well :)

Comment: thanks for your support. But now I am getting some other charcters. I am trying to fetch the emails from the http://www.quickerala.com/listings?searchString=&districtId=1&go=Go page. Please help me

Comment: @user1396530 just relax, saying 'please help me' won't make people help you harder ;-) updated my answer for the PHP code.

Comment: Thanks sir. Iam now getting the emails from that page. But still Iam really iinterested to know, is there any way to get all the emails from all pages in that web site quickkerala.com. Please help me . You are a genious and you can help me . Thanks in advance..

Comment: It is spam protection -- the entire anchor tag for the email address is reversed and escaped.  They probably don't want you to do what you're doing :)

Comment: @user1396530: The `$value` in the answer will be an `<a>` tag.  You'll have to use `DOMDocument` again to parse it, and get its `nodeValue`.

Comment: @user1396530 Thanks, you're very flattering :) the information you're looking for are in the answer though (kenobi swipe)